# Проблема со считыванием List из файла и переносом в другой List

Tags: java

У меня такая проблема - мне нужно считать из файла заранее помещенный туда список, после чего передать этот список в Мэйн и добавить в другой лист.
Из файла считал, все нормально. Только в итоге получаю лист, в котором под индексом 0 лежит лист, в котором уже лежат мои объекты.
Соответственно, когда такой лист я передаю в Мэйн и добавляю к другому листу, структура сохраняется. А мне же надо как то доставать список объектов из этой структуры и помещать его как нормальный список в мой лист, который в мэйне. Как это реализовать? Пытался стримами, не очень получилось. Пробовал примерно так:
`mylist.add(Stream.of(method.load().stream (тут пытался мапить и так далее, но не очень получилось).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Как то так. Извините за минимум кода, писал с телефона. Помогите разобраться пж)

Comment: mylist.add не нужен. коллектор сам создает лист. должно быть примерно так: mylist = Stream.of(method.load().stream (тут пытался мапить и так далее, но не очень получилось).collect(Collectors.toList())

Answer (score 1):

Вместо mylist.add(..) надо написать mylist.addAll(..)
Смотри у Оракла:
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)

Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection (optional operation). The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this collection, and this collection is nonempty.)